# Who is this certification ([KA] in a square)?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

[image: Sample Image of Certification]

Which organization uses this symbol?

It was seen on a package of candy (Goody Good Stuff is the brand) in the Netherlands.

Comment: How do you know it stands for kosher?

Comment: @147zcbm, placement of the symbol on the packaging. A symbol organized around the letter K on a food package that does not mean Kosher would be a first in my life.

Comment: Have you sent them an email asking the name of the agency? http://goodygoodstuff.com/en/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certification is apparently from the Chief Rabbi of Austria, Rabbi Dr. Paul Chaim Eisenberg.

(Trail of evidence is from [the company web site](http://goodygoodstuff.com/en/) to the [certificate](http://goodygoodstuff.com/en/certificates/kosher) to [the profile](http://www.jewishtelegraph.com/prof_145.html))

I guess the KA stands for Kosher Austria.

Comment: There is also a KA certification in Mexico, but their symbol is very different. http://www.ka-kosher.com

Comment: This appears to be their website: http://www.ikg-wien.at/?page_id=775&lang=en

Comment: @JJLL, there is also [Kosher Authority](http://www.ka.org.au/) of Australia, which is a KA in a diamond.